# How to plot categorical variables with a pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am concerned with a single column (`fruit`) from my `df`:

```
| fruit               |
| --------------------|  
| apple, orange       | 
| banana              |
| grapefruit, orange  |
| apple, banana, kiwi |
```

I want to plot the values from `fruit` to a pie chart to get a visual representation of the distribution of each individual fruit

I run: `df.plot(kind='pie', y='fruit')`

But this gives a `TypeError`: `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I have read: [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

But I can't see how it helps solve my problem

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `split` and `explode`:

```
(df['fruit']
 .str.split(',\s*')
 .explode()
 .value_counts()
 .plot(kind='pie')
)
```

Output:

[image: pie chart]